# Wordpress CMB2 qTranslate-x

Tags: wordpress, cmb2

How to make CMB2 box compatible with qTranslate-x?

I have simple text field created with CMB2 (https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/cmb2/).

```
$cmb_demo->add_field( array(
  'name' => __( 'Text', $this->plugin_slug ),
  'desc' => __( 'field description (optional)', $this->plugin_slug ),
  'id' => $prefix . $this->plugin_slug . '_text',
  'type' => 'text'
) );
```

How can I make its content available for qTranslate-x plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there wasn't any Wordpress plugin which will provide such integration, so I created new project. It could be found on Github https://github.com/jmarceli/integration-cmb2-qtranslate as well as on Wordpress.org https://wordpress.org/plugins/integration-cmb2-qtranslate/.

Comment: I am having an issue with the wysiwyg field in that after saving it doesn't show the right text in the editor window after switching tabs. - the value is incorrect on the element.

Comment: @AndrewWelch Check my solution to this on the [github](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/issues/519). It works on wysiwyg

Comment: I've just fixed wysiwyg support in my module. Please check if it is working now for you.